# Fetch User's email address from Twitter using Twitter4j Library in android

Tags: android, email, twitter, callback, twitter4j

I am unable to get the email address of user's who is logging into my app via Twitter. Twitter Callback with Fabric provides the callback methods to get the email address, below is the code for getting the email address.

```
TwitterAuthClient authClient = new TwitterAuthClient();

            authClient.requestEmail(session, new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result<String> result) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onSuccess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("MainActicity Email : ", result.data);
                    tvEmail.setText(result.data + "\n" + session.getUserName() + "\n" + session.getUserId());
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onFailure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("MainActicity Email 2 : ", e.toString());
                    tvEmail.setText("User Don't want to share Email Address" + "\n" + session.getUserName());
                }
            });
```

In this way I am able to get the email address. But this method uses Retrofit 1.9 and I used Retrofit 2.0 in my project. This collision is generating error something called as "verify-error". I can't degrade my Retrofit 2.0 to lower at this point. So, I thought of getting email address with different approach. Another approach is by using Twitter4j. In this I am able to get all the details except email address. If we don't get the email address of a user while sign up, then what is the use of using Twitter login.

Please provide me some help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way in getting email address using twitter4j/Twitter REST API. Use Twitter Kit instead.

There's no other solution except twitter kit. take note that email in twitter is optional you can use either phone number or email , so there's no guarantee that every user put email address on their account.

Comment: But I told you already what is the problem when I use Twitter kit. Please give me another solution for this.

Comment: can we get phone number using twitter4j??

Comment: Then what is the use of Sign up via Twitter. It is waste if it doesn't provide the main information of user's.